# How can I merged ResourceDictionary of userControl into app.xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I created UserControl and wrote ResourcesDictionary. There are some Styles.

And I want to Merge ResourceDictionary into App.xaml.

But Main Project is A, and there is App.xaml.

And UserControl is in B project, so they live another place.

How Can I merged ResourceDictonary ?

Here is part of my code, but it is not work.

**First Try in App.xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="myUserControl.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> ......
```

**Second Try**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/B;component/SubFolderName/myUserControl.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> ......
```

**Third Try**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/B;component/SubFolderName/myUserControl.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> ......
```

They all didn't work.....

**+ myUserControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="........."
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:B"
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="300" d:DesignHeight="100">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <Style x:Key="TitleTest" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="PanelTestStyle" TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Setter Property="ClipToBounds" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="55"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="TestStyle2" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40"/>
        </Style>           
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusTitle}" Style="{DynamicResource TitleTest}"/>
    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource PanelTestStyle}">
        <TextBlock x:Name="testText" Style="{DynamicResource TestStyle2}" Text="{Binding StatusNumber}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="testText2" Style="{DynamicResource TestStyle2}" Text="TEST" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

In addition, I want to get Setter Value to change FontSize in cs code, so i need to set DynamicResource (TextBlocks).

Comment: Can u post the xaml of your myUserControl.xaml?

Comment: you can't merge a control into a dictionary, either move the Xaml from the User control into the App's resource section or create it at a stand-alone Resource dictionary

Comment: @MikeT Yes, that's why I asked for the xaml code to be sure he really tries to merge with a UserControl.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom  I posted myUserControl.xaml !

Comment: @MikeT I already tried to move resources into the App.xaml's resource section. Then, I couldn't set DynamicResource Style. There is no error, but not work. I could check Value of Setter changed, but it didn't apply. I don't know why... :(

Comment: @parfum Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your ResourceDictionary in a sepereate xaml file; not in the App.xaml. This file has to look like:

```
 <ResourceDictionary>
     <Style x:Key="TitleTest" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTextBlock}">
         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15"/>
         <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
         <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
         <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
     </Style>
...
```

If you want to use this ResourceDictionary in the same dll you can access it with using the code of your first try. If you want to use it in another dll you cann access it with using the code of your second try.

Comment: Good luck. If it work's I would be thankfull if you would accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You must have a reference to project 'B' in your project 'A', and then your example 'Second Try' should work